# formating csv files using FasterCsv - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I'm using FasterCsv to export data to CSV files in rails.Now I want to format the values in CSV file

```
  title = ["NAME", "ID", "INSTITUTION"]
  output.write FasterCSV.generate_line(title)
```

like coloring, Bold etc.

how to do that?any help..

Comment: If this is Ruby 1.9, note that FasterCSV is now the implementation for the built-in CSV library.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to style in a CSV file, it is just raw data, and csv is meant for plain text format file..

refer this sitepoint link for reference..
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=532277

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you can't add formatting to CSV files.

CSV means, literally, "Comma Separated Values". This is, a plain text file with values, separated with commas. Formatting isn't included.

If you want to include formatting (for Excel, I pressume) you will have to generate a different kind of file - for example an xls file.

You can do so by using the [Spreadsheet gem](http://rubyforge.org/projects/spreadsheet).

I haven't personally used that gem for formatting. After a quick google search I found [this forum](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37647) on which they show how to use it for changing the format of a cell (background color on this case). Warning: I haven't tried this code myself and I'm not 100% certain it is current.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

class ColorFormat < Spreadsheet::Format
  def initialize(color)
    super :pattern => 1, :pattern_fg_color => color
  end
end

sheet = book.create_worksheet :name => 'My fruits'

fruits = {
  'apple' => :red,
  'lemon' => :yellow,
  'orange' => :orange
}.each_with_index do |(fruit, color), i|
  sheet[0, i] = fruit
  sheet.row(0).set_format(i, ColorFormat.new(color))
end

sheet.row(0).height = 14 

book.write '/home/serge/Documents/fruits.xls'
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a plain text file format, AFAIK you cant supply font attributes in it.